# Meteoric Cordova App - Local DB or REST API?

Tags: cordova, rest, meteor

I've been experimenting with the Meteor + Ionic package, and it works pretty well for me.

I noticed that when making a local DB, the size of the app grows to large numbers (from 3-4MB to 50+).

I feel as though a Meteor/Cordova app should NOT use a local DB, and just rely on a REST API.

What do you guys think? Local phone DB or store data on a cloud server?

Comment: What local db do you mean, is it ground:db? The database used when you run `meteor`, mongodb to be specific, is on the server side and not on the mobile app itself. It would be using DDP which is Meteor's parallel to REST.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ground:db. I'm not running `meteor`, I'm porting the app to my Android device ala Phonegap. It seems as though the database is stored on the phone device, which causes the app size to expand.

Answer (score 0):

How are you porting the app? Meteor has a built in command to add platforms and export the apk. There is no such thing as localDB in a meteor generated apk.